# AttributeError: module 'UI' has no attribute 'ui_1'

Tags: python, import, module

can any one tell me why

`from UI import ui_1` works but not `import UI as u` and `from UI import *`
if following code

```
# DOESNT WORK: import UI as u
# DOESNT WORK: from UI import *
from UI import ui_1

def main():
    print("main initialised")
    ui_1.test_function()


main()
```

[image: file structure]

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax is:

```
from <package> import <module> as <local name alias>    # to import a module from package with the alias name
import <package>.<module> as <local name alias>         # relative import module from package with the alias name
import <package> as <local name alias>                  # rename package with the alias name
```

By placing an `__init__.py` file in UI folder, UI is now the package name.

So this import just renames the module you import:

```
import UI as u
```

To access the contents of ui_1:

```
u.ui_1.<class, definition or variable>
```

As for why `from UI import *` won't work, the python docs tell us:

> 6.4.1. Importing * From a Package
>
> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit index of the package. The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s **init**.py code defines a list named **all**, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered. It is up to the package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the package is released.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

So in `__init__.py` put:

```
__all__ = ["ui_1"]
```